# When I click the button, I want to change the page background color to another color, not black, how can I do it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

> ```
> const DarkTheme = () => {
>   const [dark, setDark] = useState(false)
>
>   const theme = createMuiTheme({
>       palette: {
>           type: dark ? 'dark' : 'light',`I want to make another color instead of dark`
>       },
>   })
> ```

When I click the button, I want to change the page background color to another color, not black, how can I do it?

> ```
>   return (
>       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
>            //toggle
>           <Switch checked={dark} onChange={() => setDark(!dark)} />
>           <Paper>
>               <Typography variant='h1'>This is a h1 text</Typography>
>
>               <Typography variant='body2'>This is a body2 text</Typography>
>           </Paper>
>       </ThemeProvider>
>   )
> }
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: You can refer here https://mui.com/customization/dark-mode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the customize `palette` design to create your own dark mode.

Like here I have created `pink color` background for *dark mode* and `blue text` in l**ight mode**.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { amber, pink,blue } from '@mui/material/colors';

import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import Switch from '@mui/material/Switch';



export default function Palette() {

  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);
  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      dark,
    primary: {
      ...amber,
      ...(dark === true && {
        main: amber[300],
      }),
    },
    ...(dark === true && {
      background: {
        default: pink[900],
        paper: pink[900],
      },
    }),
    text: {
      ...(dark === false
        ? {
            primary: blue[900],
            secondary: blue[800],
          }
        : {
            primary: '#fff',
            secondary: blue[500],
          }),
    },
    },
    });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      
      <Switch checked={dark} onChange={() => setDark(!dark)} />
        <Paper>
          <Typography variant='h1'>This is a h1 text</Typography>

              <Typography variant='body2'>This is a body2 text</Typography>
          </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend it helped a lot

Comment: Type '{ text: { primary: "#0d47a1"; secondary: "#1565c0"; } | { primary: string; secondary: "#2196f3"; }; background?: { default: "#880e4f"; paper: "#880e4f"; } | undefined; dark: boolean; primary: { main?: "#ffd54f" | undefined; ... 13 more ...; A700: "#ffab00"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'PaletteOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dark' does not exist in type 'PaletteOptions'.ts(2322)

Comment: i am getting an error like this

Comment: Do not assign it to `type`. You can simply copy paste my code? If problem occurs again, then I will share you the codesandbox  link

Comment: i shared my problem